# Android EditText(TextView) декорация текста

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Мне нужно чтобы когда в `EditText` пользователь вводил данные (например `100000000` или `+712361000000`) то они разделялись точками или пробелами (на выходе что-то типа: `100.000.000` или `+7 123 61000000`).

Как это реализовать?

Comment: можете попробовать создать свои маски с помощью данной либы - https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro#using-custom-mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создать свою собственную имплементацию класса потомка `EditText`.

Для начала возьмите исходники таковых реализаций (их много) и изучите как там все это сделано.

[Примеры здесь](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=maskededittext&type=Repositories)